# signalR is timing out

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, signalr

I am using signalR for a 1-1 chat application. In other words, only one user can chat at a time.

signalR is starting up correctly, but later it is timing out.

Is there a relation between this behavior and the fact that the Firewall on my public server? Is there a possibility Firewall is thinking a service is flooding it with requests?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the firewall to be honest, but have you tried setting keepalive on the configuration in the application_start method in the global.asax file, for example

```
GlobalHost.Configuration.KeepAlive = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60);
```

Comment: Allows access to commonly used items in signalr.  To use this type reference SignalR.Hosting.Common.dll.